# Boost Spirit: Error C2664, Cannot convert 'const boost::phoenix::actor<Eval>' to 'char'

Tags: c++, json, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I'm new to Boost Spirit and trying to write JSON parser using Boost Spirit 2.4.2 (Boost 1.46.1). For the code below, I get the error when trying to execute semantic action/attribute:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'void (char)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::phoenix::actor<Eval>' to 'char'
```

I saw some questions but they don't really apply to my case. Please kindly help. Thank you!

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_container.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_function.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_assoc_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

void print_char(char c)
{
    std::cout << c;
}

template <typename Iterator>
struct json_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, ascii::space_type>
{
    json_grammar() : json_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        using ascii::alpha;
        using ascii::alnum;
        using qi::long_long;
        using qi::long_double;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::char_;
        using qi::lexeme;
        typedef boost::function<void(char)> char_action_t;

        //char_action_t beginObj  (boost::bind(&print_char, qi::_1));

        // 
        start =
            char_('{')          [boost::bind(&print_char, qi::_1)]
            >> -(js_member % ',')
            >> char_('}')
        ;
        // 
        js_member =
            js_key
            >> ':' >> js_value
        ;
        // 
        js_key = (alpha >> *alnum) | js_string
        ;
        // 
        js_string = js_single_quoted_str | js_double_quoted_str
        ;
        // 
        js_array = lit('[') >> -(js_value % ',') >> lit(']')
        ;
        // 
        js_bool = lit("true") | lit("false")
        ;
        // 
        js_null = lit("null")
        ;
        // 
        js_value = js_string | js_num | js_array | start | js_bool | js_null | js_empty_str;
        // 
        js_single_quoted_str = (lexeme["'" >> +((char_ | ' ' | "\t") - "'") >> "'"]);
        // 
        js_double_quoted_str = (lexeme['"' >> +((char_ | ' ' | "\t") - '"') >> '"']);
        // 
        js_empty_str = lit("''") | lit("\"\"");
        // 
        js_num = long_long | long_double;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_member;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_key;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_value;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_single_quoted_str;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_double_quoted_str;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_empty_str;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_array;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_num;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_null;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> js_bool;
};

int main()
{
    std::string inputStr;
    json_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> jsonParser;
    bool parseOK = false;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, inputStr)) {
        if(inputStr.empty() || inputStr[0] == 'q' || inputStr[0] == 'Q')
            break;

        std::string::const_iterator iter = inputStr.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator iterEnd = inputStr.end();

        parseOK = qi::phrase_parse(iter, iterEnd, jsonParser, ascii::space);

        if(parseOK && iter == iterEnd) {
            std::cout << "Successfully parsed the input as JSON!" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Cannot parse the input as JSON!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are aware of json spirit (e.g. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/json-spirit/4.04-1)?

Comment: Thanks sehe. It uses classic Spirit, while I'm using version 2.4.2 (the latest & greatest). There are significant differences, IMHO. Moreover, the code is too complicated for Spirit beginner like me. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: If your compiler supports C++0x take a look at the AXE parser generator, parsing JSON can't be any simpler. In fact it has an example of JSON parser in version 1.0.10.99.

Comment: Thanks Gene. I prefer open source stuff like Boost Spirit and I'm learning to write a decent parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More update:

Kostya has a good point and 'half' touches base: `boost::bind` actually is fine, just use different placeholders :

```
[ boost::bind(&print_char, ::_1) ]
[ phoenix::bind(&print_char, qi::_1) ]
[ print_char ]
```

All three should work, but not mixed :)

Comment: It's actually `[ boost::bind(&print_char, ::_1) ]`, and yes `_1` is in global namespace.

Comment: Fixed, tyvm Hartmut (I was in slight doubt; I knew there was something strange there with boost::bind -- I remember now that I was surprised about getting spurious ambiguous identifier there some time ago).

Comment: Right, I have arrived at the same conclusion, @sehe. Thanks to @hkaiser too.

Comment: Gentlemen, may I have your attention redirected to the next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551806/boost-spirit-2-4-2-cannot-extract-a-string . Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Seems that `boost::bind` is not very good to use with spirit. I remember that it was recommended to use `phoenix` instead. I've replaced the line in consideration with:

```
   char_('{') [std::cout << boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1]
```

It compiles. Have no time to check if it actually works.